# How to retrieve the recently added file from fs.chunks in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I want to retrieve the recently added file from fs.chunks in mongodb. Presently I am using:

`mongodump --collection fs.chunks --db xcontent`

This does give the recently added file in as `dump/xcontent/fs.chunks.bson` (where fs.chunks.bson is the retrieved file), but it has a huge size (nearly 56MB while the original file was around 256KB). Is there any efficient way to retrieve the recently added file?

Note: All queries should be on ubuntu terminal

Comment: Are you using any scripting language? gridfs still has a metadata collection with a standard objectid as the primary key. You can use the same method against this collection as you would others to find the latest inserted document, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/#gridfs-files-collection.

db.files.findOne().sort({_id: -1})

This will give you the latest id inserted into the files collection, now you can grab the actual file, if you need it.

Comment: I want to do this via ubuntu terminal only. What should I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `mongofiles` command line utility for working with files stored in GridFS:

```
$ mongofiles --db xcontent put README
connected to: 127.0.0.1
added file: { _id: ObjectId('53eb8f189ea8e0b398ca163c'), filename: "README", chunkSize: 261120, uploadDate: new Date(1407946520706), md5: "b942ff0beef2b24602289051e6bc9938", length: 1860 }
done!

$ mongofiles --db xcontent  list
connected to: 127.0.0.1
README  1860

$ mongofiles --db xcontent get README
connected to: 127.0.0.1
done write to: README
```

For MongoDB 2.6, `mongofiles` is included in the [`mongodb-org-tools` package](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), which is also installed by the `mongodb-org` metapackage.